# Bicycle Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

A student watches two people coast down a hill on bikes. They both start from rest. Neither one of them peddles the bike. Gravity is the ONLY driving force. Friction and air resistance are negligible. Of the two people, the person with the larger mass reaches the bottom of the hill significantly earlier than the person with less mass. Explain why this happens.

Comment: It's not possible. In the absence of friction both experience the same downhill acceleration $a=g\sin\theta$, with $\theta$ the angle of the slope with respect to the horizontal.

Comment: Perhaps the person with more mass started further down the hill. This is a brain teaser, not physics.

Comment: An approach to thinking about this is to ask where the potential energy goes: some of it goes into translational kinetic energy, but some of it goes somewhere else: where, in the absence of frictional losses?

Comment: @Gert - this is not true, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Calculating_moment_of_inertia_about_an_axis

Comment: @СимонТыран: sure, if you take $I$ of the wheels into account but let's try and stay serious, please. ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Please note that this is not a homework site. Most questions of homework-type (and this includes many questions that are *not* explicitly the coursework for some academic institution) or "check-my-work"-type are off-topic here. In particular, for your question to be well-received, it is important that you (1) show some effort of your own (2) ask a *conceptual* question. For more info, see e.g. [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming they have identical bicycles with wheels having moment of inertia $I$ and radius $R$, their velocity after dropping a height $H$ is given by

$$ v^2=\frac{2\cdot g\cdot H}{1+\frac{I}{m\cdot R^2}}$$

Thus the larger $m$ has a larger velocity.

Comment: please note that friction cannot be negligible, otherwise the bicycles would skid, not roll. Friction depends on the normal force and the complete problem should take it into account,

Answer (score 1):

This could be explained if the wheels on the bicycle ridden by the person with the larger mass had a smaller moment of inertia.
If the wheels have a moment of inertia then the loss of gravitational potential energy is equal to the gain in translational kinetic energy of the centre of mass bicycle and rider plus the gain in rotational kinetic energy of the wheels.
For a larger moment of inertia the proportion of rotational kinetic energy increases and so the proportion of translational kinetic energy ($\propto v^2_{\textrm{translational}}$) decreases.